# SQL Return Unique Count from 3 Columns - DateTime, Vehicle, Driver

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to process the below data in my database to return out unique drivers of a given vehicle (in this case 'Car 1') for a given timestamp. This is a made up example but should suffice.

My Code so far - Which doesn't quite get to what I want:

```
USE 
    VehicleUse
SELECT
    DISTINCT((CONVERT(VARCHAR, m.CurrentDateTime,20) + ' ' + v.VehicleName + ' ' + m.Driver)) AS [Unique Combo]
    , count(m.CurrentDateTime)
FROM
    Vehicles AS v INNER JOIN
    MainData AS m
    ON l.VehicleID = m.VehicleID
WHERE
    v.VehicleName = 'Car 1' 
GROUP BY
    m.CurrentDateTime 
    , v.VehicleName
    , m.Driver  
ORDER BY 
    [Unique Combo]
```

An Example: Pre-Processed

```
+---------------------+---------+--------+
|      Date Time      | Vehicle | Driver |
+---------------------+---------+--------+
| 2014-01-01 10:01:00 | Car 1   | A      |
| 2014-01-01 10:01:00 | Car 1   | B      |
| 2014-01-01 10:01:00 | Car 1   | B      |
| 2014-01-01 10:03:00 | Car 1   | C      |
| 2014-01-01 10:03:00 | Car 1   | C      |
| 2014-01-01 10:03:00 | Car 1   | D      |
| 2014-01-01 10:03:00 | Car 1   | E      |
| 2014-01-01 10:03:00 | Car 1   | F      |
| 2014-01-01 10:05:00 | Car 1   | A      |
| 2014-01-01 10:05:00 | Car 1   | B      |
| 2014-01-01 10:05:00 | Car 1   | C      |
| 2014-01-01 10:05:00 | Car 1   | D      |
| 2014-01-01 10:05:00 | Car 1   | E      |
+---------------------+---------+--------+
```

Current Results:

```
+-----------------------------+-------+
|        Unique Combo         | Count |
+-----------------------------+-------+
| 2014-01-01 10:01:00 Car 1 A |     1 |
| 2014-01-01 10:01:00 Car 1 B |     2 |
| 2014-01-01 10:03:00 Car 1 C |     2 |
| 2014-01-01 10:03:00 Car 1 D |     1 |
| 2014-01-01 10:03:00 Car 1 E |     1 |
| 2014-01-01 10:03:00 Car 1 F |     1 |
| 2014-01-01 10:05:00 Car 1 A |     1 |
| 2014-01-01 10:05:00 Car 1 B |     1 |
| 2014-01-01 10:05:00 Car 1 C |     1 |
| 2014-01-01 10:05:00 Car 1 D |     1 |
| 2014-01-01 10:05:00 Car 1 E |     1 |
+-----------------------------+-------+
```

Desired Results:

```
+---------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|      Date Time      | Vehicle | Unique Driver Count For Vehicle @ DateTime |
+---------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-01 10:01:00 | Car 1   |                                          2 |
| 2014-01-01 10:03:00 | Car 1   |                                          4 |
| 2014-01-01 10:05:00 | Car 1   |                                          5 |
+---------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What part doesn't work?

Comment: (Thanks for adding the <pre>!) The code above does work but it doesnt generate the table I want - I want to be able to count that there are 2 unique drivers of Car 1 at DateTime 2014-01-01 10:01:00 for example as pre the second table. My method reruns a unique count of the Unique Combo and not the unique count per vehicle per timestamp. Thanks

Comment: If you include the output of your current query in the question that might help people see where you are now as well as where you are trying to get to.

Comment: Updated with current Results.

Comment: Ahh, I see. At the moment you are getting "how many times has each driver during X" what you want is "how many different drivers are there during X".

Comment: Hi Tim, Thats exactly correct - Per Vehicle of course. Or should I say for the given Vehicle on the SQL command. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure on the exact syntax for the flavour of SQL you are using, but I think you want to group on name and date, and then count the drivers.

```
SELECT
    m.CurrentDateTime, v.VehicleName, count(distinct m.Driver)
FROM
    Vehicles AS v INNER JOIN
    MainData AS m
    ON l.VehicleID = m.VehicleID
WHERE
    v.VehicleName = 'Car 1' 
GROUP BY
    m.CurrentDateTime 
    , v.VehicleName
ORDER BY 
    m.CurrentDateTime 
    , v.VehicleName
```

Comment: BINGO! Thats the Ticket! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT m.CurrentDateTime AS ' Date Time',v.VehicleName ,COUNT(m.Driver) AS 'Unique Driver Count For Vehicle @ DateTime '
FROM
    Vehicles  v 
    INNER JOIN MainData  m ON l.VehicleID = m.VehicleID
WHERE
    v.VehicleName = 'Car 1' 
GROUP BY
    m.CurrentDateTime 
    , v.VehicleName
ORDER BY CurrentDateTime
```

Comment: Hi 'sureshhh'. This result is correct for 'Concurrent' drivers per vehicle per Timestep. What I require is 'Unique' Drivers Per Timestep Vehicle Combo.